# Unable to spawn entity with summon command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I've been trying to make an adventure map, but I can't summon the boss, because it keeps saying "*Unable to summon object*". 

Here's the command I'm using:

`summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"Uncle",Health:100.0f,HandItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_sword}, {Count:1,id:shield}],UUIDLeast:-6645587150281567948L,UUIDMost:4420078606457655279L}`

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is probably your CustomName. Since 1.13, the name must be enclosed with quotations followed by a backslash, without removing the original quotations.

An example:

```
summon aquid ~ ~ ~ {CustomName:"\"Zoidberg\""}
```

Your original command with those changes looks like this:

summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~1 ~ {CustomName:"\"Uncle\"",Health:100.0f,HandItems:[{Count:1,id:diamond_sword}, {Count:1,id:shield}],UUIDLeast:-6645587150281567948L,UUIDMost:4420078606457655279L}

Answer (score 0):

to me it seems that the main issue is in your items tags. the format for that in most cases is `{HandItems:[{id:"id_here",Count:1}]}`, whereas you have it as `{HandItems:[{Count:1,id:id_here}]}`.